# Trouble with textures in three.js examples

Tags: three.js

I'm experiencing some trouble with the Three.js examples. You can see in the image below, it seems to be working fine online, but it's not working on my desktop. I change the code trying to figure out whats wrong, and the problem seems to be on the texture loading. You see, if I change the texture material to some basic color it work, but with a texture, don't. Can you guys tell me what it's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your examples are not displaying, but I expect that your answer is in the Three.js wiki on how to run things locally.

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/How-to-run-things-locally.