# Loading texture in JavaScript (Three.js) - Access to restricted URI denied

Tags: javascript, security, opengl-es, three.js, uri

I have a problem with loading texture in JavaScript (Three.js). The program works fine (it render few objects), but when I add:

```
 var grzybSkin = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('grzybuv.png');
 grzybSkin.repeat.set( 1,1);
 grzybSkin.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping; 
 grzybSkin.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping; 
 grzybSkin.anisotropy = 16;

 var texturaGrztb = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: grzybSkin});

 var geometry_grzyb;
 var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
 loader.load( "grzyb.js", function( geometry_grzyb ) {
  for (var i = 0;i < 4;i++)
  {
   grzyb[i] = new THREE.Mesh( geometry_grzyb, texturaGrztb );
   grzyb[i].scale.set( 15, 18,  1);
   scene.add( grzyb[i] );
   grzyb[i].position.set(
   5000, 
   5000, 
   5000
  ); 
  } 
  });
```

The error occurs:

```
NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI: Access to restricted URI denied
```

And it points to `Three.js`:

```
xhr.open( "GET", url, true );
xhr.withCredentials = this.withCredentials;
xhr.send( null );
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12347920/trouble-with-textures-in-three-js-examples/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browsers don't allow loading of resources from local files (I assume you are accessing your files directly through filesystem in a "file://c:/dir/file.html" manner) and also it won't allow you to access resources from different domain that the site's.

In order to develop and debug THREE.js locally, you will have to set up a local webserver -  best options being XAMPP, WAMP or similar project.